# (International) Are the non-final office actions publicly searchable or published online or findable using the patent application number?

Tags: international, search, databases, office-action

Are non-final office actions publicly searchable?
If an attorney claims they receive an office action, is there anyway the client may find the letter of the non-final action the attorney received by searching the patent application number without asking the attorney for an original copy of the non-final office action the attorney received?

Comment: Findable but not necessarily   searchable, as by by keyword for example.

Comment: Same answer for both non-final and final office actions and all other written back-and-forth between the applicant and the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the register of the patent office is public, yes, you can, but only once the patent application is public. For example, for the USPTO, you just need to browse the files of your case in the [Patent Center](https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/). For the EPO, you have the [European Patent Register](https://register.epo.org/advancedSearch?lng=en&clnrefer=yes), and so on for other patent offices.

Comment: And it generally becomes public at the 18 month point when the application is published.